# Node.JS windows service cannot start

Tags: node.js, windows-services

I'm using [windows-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-service) package to run my script as a windows service.

```
if (process.argv[2] == "--add") {
    logger.info('Starting to add service', global.appRoot + "\\app.js")
    ws.add (config.service_name, {programPath: global.appRoot + "\\app.js"});
    logger.info('Service added', config.service_name, global.appRoot + "\\app.js")
} else if (process.argv[2] == "--remove") {
    logger.info('Removing service', config.service_name)
    ws.remove (config.service_name);
    logger.info('Service removed', config.service_name)
} else if (process.argv[2] == "--run") {
    logger.info('Starting service', config.service_name);
    ws.run (logger, function() {
        logger.info('Stopping service', config.service_name);
        ws.stop()
        logger.info('Service stopped')      
    });
} else if (process.argv[2] == "--stop") {
    logger.info('Stopping service', config.service_name);
    ws.stop()
    logger.info('Service stopped')
}
```

After running "node service.js --add", I have verified that my windows service is installed correctly with command like below

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "E:\Utils\app.js"
```

I pasted the command into node.js command prompt and it launched the script correctly.

However, when I tried to start the windows service from the service console, it always complains

```
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashiion.
```

I tried "node service.js --run", it simply prints out the "Starting service" message and hangs there. The underlying script isn't kicked off either.

Verified service log, no error. No script-specific log is generated.

All my script objects are using global.appPath for absolute path reference.

I run out of ideas. Any advice on this matter?

Comment: I presume `logger` will be writing to some sort of log file, have you checked that?

Comment: James, there're two log files the code is supposed to generate, service log for the windows service itself and script log for the underlying script. Service log looks perfectly normal and no script log is generated.

Comment: Does your `app.js` run fine standalone? i.e. not being run as a windows service?

Comment: Yes. app.js runs ok, even when I manually copy out the windows service's command, it run fine, but I'm not able to start the windows service

Comment: Hmm what about permissions? I am pretty sure you need to be an administrator to start/stop services, have you tried running your app with elevated permissions?

Comment: The service is running as local system account. That should be enough, I suppose? I myself am also an administrator.

Comment: Irrespective of what account the windows service is running under, the app triggering the start/stop of the service would require elevated permissions. However, if you are sure this is all being done as an admin already then I doubt that will be the problem, could you provide a snippet of what your service code is doing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77593/discussion-between-lee-and-james).